# Is the function $\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ Continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

The function is defined piece-wise with $f(0,0) = 0$, so I took the limit $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

I proceeded like this:

$$\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  \leq \frac{|y|(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq \frac{|y|(x^4+4x^2y^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} 
$$
$$= \frac{|y|(x^2+y^2)^2+|y|2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} =  |y| + \frac{|y|2(xy)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq |y| + \frac{|y|2(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2})^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = |y| + \frac{|y|}{2} \rightarrow0$$

Hence by the sandwich/squeeze theorem, the original function also goes to $0$

Is this answer ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your proof looks good, very good.

Your problem is a special case of this result: Suppose $p(x,y),q(x,y)$ are homogeneous polynomials with $\deg p > \deg q,$ and $q(x,y)\ne 0$ except at $(0,0).$ Then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}=0.$$

A popular way of proving this is to go to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct but here is shorter way.

Since $|x|,|y|\le \|(x,y)\|$
we get  $$\left|\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|=\left|\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{\|(x,y)\|^4}\right|\le 6\frac{\|(x,y)\|^5}{\|(x,y)\|^4} =\|(x,y)\|\to 0$$